# Testing Translation

Tags: release-freya, system

I started translating elementary OS into Georgian language. Now I want to test my translations. I can download translated .po or .mo files from Launchpad but where should I place them? 
And one more question. How much time is needed for translations to show up in updates?

Thanks for your great distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translation, you are working on today, you will see in the next release Loki. If you want it now, you need to install Pantheon on Ubuntu 16.04 base (I recommend to use VM).

1. Download and install Xenial [daily build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).
2. Add repositories with elementary packages using terminal: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily -y && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches -y`
3. Update package lists from the repositories and install DE using terminal: `sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop`
4. Upgrade your system: `sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. Reboot to Pantheon and select Georgian language in settings.

Packages with updated translations appear in repositories everyday, about 9:00 AM on Moscow/Georgian time.